# ArrayList of ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist

How to trace the elements in the ArrayList of ArrayList of String elements and create a        HashMap from it? I need to know how to access the string elements in each of the inner     ArrayList and if its unique add it as a key in the HashMap and set its count to 1, any    subsequent presence of that particular string in any inner ArrayList would increment the count for that String.

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: please share the code u have written till now and where are u getting stuck in that

Comment: And perhaps an example to demonstrate

Comment: What do you mean by "trace the elements"? Without an example of sample input and expected output, it's not terribly easy to tell what you mean. What's the significance of the list nesting?

Answer (score 2):

Just because I'm in a good mood:

```
List<List<String>> outer = getOuter();
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
for(List<String> inner : outer) {
  for(String word : inner) {
    if(!wordCount.contains(word)) {
      wordCount.put(word,1);
    } else {
      wordCount.put(word,wordCount.get(word)+1);
    }
  }
}
```